# Django Threading Structure

Tags: python, django, server, django-templates

First of all to begin with 'Yes' i checked and googled this topic but can't find anything that gives me a clear answer to my question? I am a beginner in **Djagno** and studying its documentation where i read about the **Thread Safety Considerations for render method of nodes for Templates Tags**. Here is the link to the documentation [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#thread-safety-considerations). My question lies where it states that **Once the node is parsed the render method for that node might be called multiple times** i am confused whether it is talking about the use of the template tag in the same document at different places for the same user at the single instance level of the user on the server **or** the use of the template tag for multiple request coming from users all around the world sharing the same django instance in memory? If its the **latter** one does't django create a new instance at the server level for every new user request and have separate resources for every user in the memory or am i wrong about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the latter.

A WSGI server usually runs a number of persistent processes, and in each process it runs a number of threads. While some automatic scaling can be applied, the number of processes and threads is more or less constant, and determines how many concurrent requests Django can handle. The days where each request would create a new CGI process are long gone, and in most cases persistent processes are much more efficient.

Each process has its own memory, and the communication between processes is usually handled by the database, the cache etc. They can't communicate directly through memory.

Each thread within a process shares the same memory. That means that any object that is not locally scoped (e.g. only defined inside a function), is accessible from the other threads. The cached template loader parses each template once per process, and each thread uses the same parsed nodes. That also means that if you set e.g. `self.foo = 'bar'` in one thread, each thread will then read `'bar'` when accessing `self.foo`. Since multiple threads run at the same time, this can quickly become a huge mess that's impossible to debug, which is why thread safety is so important.

As the documentation says, as long as you don't store data on `self`, but put it into `context.render_context`, you should be fine.

Comment: First of all **Thanks Man**. So here is my perception from your answer. Basically the server creates one process for all incoming requests and in each process some fixed number of threads are maintained which share the global resources of the process. That is why **Thread Safety is Required**.

Comment: Pretty much, yes. If you have a busy site you would use multiple processes that each have multiple threads, but other than that you're spot on.